# Manual performGC hugely reduces memory footprint

Tags: haskell, memory, garbage-collection, ghc

My program uses the GHC API in `IO`, doing some computation inside a `GhcMonad` and forcing the result before returning it; something like this:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    x <- runGhcT $ do
        x0 <- someGhcFunctionality
        x1 <- furtherProcessing
        liftIO . evaluate . force $ x1

    putStrLn "Done with GHC."
    _ <- getLine

    continueProcessingOutsideGhc x
```

At the pause point, I can see the process using 30+ GB of RAM; since `continueProcessingOutsideGhc` also uses some amount of memory on its own, this can lead to running out of memory in the middle of `continueProcessingOutsideGhc`.

However, what I have found is that manually forcing garbage collection at the pause point changes things drastically:

```
import System.Mem

main :: IO ()
main = do
    x <- runGhcT $ do
        x0 <- someGhcFunctionality
        x1 <- furtherProcessing
        liftIO . evaluate . force $ x1

    putStrLn "Done with GHC."
    _ <- getLine

    performGC 
    putStrLn "Done with performGC."
    _ <- getLine

    continueProcessingOutsideGhc x
```

That `performGC` line decreases the memory footprint by 85%, to about 4 GB. This is of course enough by a far margin to let `continueProcessingOutsideGhc` finish. I should also note that doing `liftIO performGC` inside `runGhcT` doesn't have the same effect; I guess that makes sense if the global GHC context is holding on to a lot of things.

What I'd like to understand is why all that garbage is left there after exiting `runGhcT` without the manual `performGC`.

Comment: You write "this can lead to running out of memory in the middle of `continueProcessingOutsideGhc`". Have you actually observed this happening, or are you just worried it might? I have the same suspicion as Daniel Wagner: the GC should run as-needed, so `continueProcessingOutsideGhc` should succeed whether you GC or not. If you can demonstrate that `performGC` actually reliably impacts whether you run out of memory, that would be an interesting bug to track down (for someone with more expertise than me).

Comment: @amalloy yeah, no, this out-of-memory situation during `continueProcessingOutsideGhc` very much does happen in practice. That's what lead me to doing `performGC` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's not much to it. The garbage collector runs when the runtime notices that it's needed -- which, generally, is when the "short-lived" generation fills up. So if you have recently generated a bunch of garbage, it's going to live a while, until you allocated a bunch of new stuff and trigger a collection.

You haven't allocated any memory (well, maybe some, but certainly not much) since the end of `runGhcT`, so you haven't triggered a collection.

Comment: But shouldn't a GC be triggered at the very least just before actually running out of memory? How does the GHC allocator interact with the OS in this area? I would hope that if GHC asks OS for more memory and OS says no, then GHC would try to free up some space by GC'ing.

Comment: I just tried it out and found that if I tell GHC to use at most 25G of RAM (with the `-M25G` RTS option), then the `GhcMonad` part finishes with just 20G of memory usage, and the whole program manages to go through without any manual `performGC` calls.  So GHC is willing to collect some of its garbage, but doesn't feel the need when "only" the OS memory is running out?!

Comment: @Cactus Er, hm. I guess in my first read of the question I assumed that `continueProcessingOutsideGhc` meant, like, outside of Haskell entirely. Like via FFI. At which point obviously the Haskell runtime can't be expected to fix itself, as it's not even in control. Are you saying that you get OOM'd even with code that is pure Haskell executing after the `runGhcT`? If so, I agree that is more puzzling.

Comment: Now that you mention it, there *is* some FFI happening during `continueProcessingOutsideGhc`. But the entirity of the function is not a single FFI call or anything like that -- it's some nontrivial Haskell code, some of it pure, some of it in IO, some of it doing FFI.

Comment: @Cactus Does the problem persist if you stub out the FFI calls?

Comment: That will be quite involved to test.